# How to sum the field with value using UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count rows with the fields `status` is equal `1` only for one sub-query before `UNION`:

```
SELECT sender, login, sex, avatar, status, 
    SUM(case when status = 1 AND receiver = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS unread_messages 
FROM messages 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON users.idUser = messages.sender 
WHERE receiver = 1
```

It works correct, but when I add `UNION` for first query:

```
... UNION SELECT receiver, login, sex, avatar, status, idMessage 
FROM messages 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON users.idUser = messages.receiver 
WHERE sender = 1 
GROUP BY receiver, sender
```

It brokes the result of counting. So, I need count rows only for first query, for `receiver`

I tried to add additional condition:

```
case when (status = 1 and receiver = 1)
```

Comment: what you have is correct? i guess it may be because of the `idMessage` column in the result you think it is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Your first and second `SELECT` have not the same fields.

You have to add the fields in both :

First select :

```
SELECT sender, login, sex, avatar, status, null idMessage
       SUM(case when status = 1 AND receiver = 1
                then 1 else 0 end) AS unread_messages
```

Second select :

```
SELECT receiver, login, sex, avatar, status, idMessage, null unread_messages
```

Comment: I have the same number of fields. look again question

Comment: Ok but you made union of idMessage with unread_messages so you have incorrect values in the result set